# Double-sided Eyelets?

Tags: tool-selection, technique-identification, leather

I have some cheap eyelet pliers and aluminium eyelets. They produce reasonable attractive results on one side but an ugly mess on the other.

[image: eyelet front][image: eyelet rear]

Often this doesn't matter as you only see one side, but for cases where you'd like a more attractive result on both sides is there a solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The double-sided ones are often called "grommets".  Good search terms are "fabric grommets" or "fabric grommet tool".  Amazon has a huge selection, including different sizes and colors.

The grommets consist of two pieces.  One is like a shaped washer that goes on the back. The other piece is similar to the eyelets you're using, but it, and the installation tool, are designed to stretch and flare the eyelet tube instead of splitting it into a "star".  Once it's installed, it looks fine on both sides.

Comment: Grommet pliers would be the best result to look for tool online.